# How secure is a Windows PC that is routed through a Linux PC?

Tags: windows, hardening, iptables

I have a Dual PC setup. Two PC's are networked together via crossover cable. The Windows PC is running Windows 7 SP1 64-bit and the Linux PC is running Slackware 14 64-bit with iptables.

My firewall and routing is essentially:

```
{DROP All protocols and ports}
{ACCEPT specific protocols and ports}

# Rules to route from Windows PC to Linux PC
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i eth1   -s 192.168.1.10   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i eth1   -s 192.168.1.10   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -o eth1   -s 192.168.1.10   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0   -s 192.168.1.10  -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward


{DROP everything not contained in any of the above rules}
```

Assuming that the Windows PC is virus-free and/or hypothethically invulnerable to viruses/trojans/backdoors etc., how secure would the Windows PC be with a properly set up Linux firewall?

Would the Windows PC still need a firewall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the scenario you describe, your Linux box is essentially acting as a network firewall for your Windows machine. So your question basically boils down to "Do I need a host-based firewall if I am already using a network firewall?"

The answer to that question is no, you don't *need* one. However, it would be *helpful* to use one. See the concept of [Defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29).

A good explanation on what host-based firewalls can do compared to network firewalls can be found in this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40349/10211).

Answer (score -2):

Security isn't a state, it's a progress. A firewall is important, but I think: virus detection on windows is a good idea, and the firewall before the windows pc too. But I would install the Windows firewall too, because you can blog programs. iptables doesn't know which program wants connect to the internet. So my oppinion: Use both firewalls.